# How to get my android app "User" at runtime?

Tags: java, android, grep

i want to find a process that was invoked by my application. 
And when i use "ps pgrep -u" i need my application "User" id.

How can i get it on runtime?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html.

EDIT: you can also use to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29 get http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html. You can then find your process in the mix and access your [user id](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#uid).